# perl oneliner to read file line by line and skip some words by position

Tags: perl

Given a log like this:

```
2022-03-30 21:05:00.266 +0200 CEST debug  Mylog
```

Is it possible to read the log line by line, parse it and skip, for example, 3rd, 4th, and 5th word (where "word" is anything separated by whitespace) with a one line command so that I would get this output?

```
2022-03-30 21:05:00.266 Mylog
```

or 3rd and 5th to have output like this?

```
2022-03-30 21:05:00.266 CEST Mylog
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
perl -lane 'splice @F, 2, 3; print "@F"'
```

- `-l` removes newlines from input and adds them to output
- `-n` reads the input line by line, running the code for each line
- `-a` splits each line on whitespace into the @F array
- [splice](http://p3rl.org/splice) removes three elements from @F starting with position 2 (numbering starts at 0)

Comment: @gianpaolo: Instead of changing @F, you can also slice it: `perl -lane 'print "@F[0, 1, 3, 5]"'`.